# synchronizing python threads reading from a queue

Tags: python-2.7, queue, python-multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded application that reads concatenated CSV files in the form of:

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4
value1,value2,value3,value4
value1,value2,value3,value4
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3
value1,value2,value3
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
```

There are multiple worker threads that will receive the 'value' lines via a queue.  Each thread will do a q.get() to get a row and process it.

The main thread will read the data putting the 'value' rows in a queue for the workers. When it encounters a HEADER, it must wait until all the worker threads are finished processing all the data currently in the queue and then the HEADER is processed  and the workers can continue with the new format of the data.

Code looks something like:

```
rowqueue=Queue.Queue()

def value_worker():
    while True:
        rowqueue.get()
        # process the row using the previous header information.
        # This could take some time

for w in range(5):
    v=threading.Thread(target=value_worker)
    v.start()

reader=csv.reader(open('DATA.csv', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    if row[0]!='HEADER1':
        rowqueue.put(row)
    else:
        ### Wait for queue to be emptied and all workers must be 
        ### finished with their last row of data
        while True:
             if rowqueue.empty(): break

        ### current implementation may have worker empty last row
        ### but still working on it...need to wait for that last 
        ### worker

        Process_HEADER()
```

The question is, how to know that all the workers are finished with that last row (and back at the rowqueue.get() before starting to process the header?